# What was the budget for the film "Hitchcock"?

Tags: production, hitchcock

Does anyone know what the budget was for the film *Hitchcock*? I read somewhere that it had a low budget, but I haven't been able to find a specific amount.

(Due to the low budget--I read--it was filmed on a short shooting schedule. So Anthony Hopkins's makeup (to look like Hitchcock) had to be devised in a way that took just 90 min. a day to put on.)

Answer (score 3):

The film's producer (Tom Pollock) reports that their agreement with Fox Searchlight Pictures was that they would stick to a budget of *approximately* $15M.

> *Finally, Fox Searchlight Pictures signed on ― with some conditions.
>   **“We had to get the budget down to $15m-something and we had to source
>   half, because that’s how studios operate today,”** says Pollock. “Ivan
>   Reitman and I put up the money ourselves through Cold Spring Pictures,
>   through which we have previously invested in Up In The Air and No
>   Strings Attached.”* - <sub><sup>[Screendaily interview](http://www.screendaily.com/features/awards-countdown/hitchcock-psycho-path/5049543.article)</sup></sub>

The movie itself was [filmed over 35 days,](http://bbook.com/film/behind-hitchcock-and-beyond-with-director-sacha-gervasi/) implying that more than 70-80% of their total budget was spent on "below the line" costs such as filming (cinematography/lights), talent costs (actors), effects/makeup and post-editing.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it was 15 to 16 million according to  [THE HOLLYWOOD REPORTER](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/hitchcock-anthony-hopkins-helen-mirren-395555), which states 15.7 million. Half by Montecito and the other half by Fox Searchlight.